# Best way to limit account creation to paid users

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, authentication

We are developing a simple app with Phonegap/Cordova which asks users to create an account first to access the content. As an added layer of protection for the API abuse, we would like to limit account creation by allowing only the person who made the purchase before the download to create this account.

If possible, what would be the best way to achieve this goal on iOS?

Comment: I think your approach is wrong. What problem are you really trying to solve?

Comment: What I want is to be sure that all the accounts created on the app only represents paid subscribers. I don't want people who choose to get the app via unofficial routes and people who want to create secondary accounts on the same device to be able to access the data provided within the app.

Comment: @Ali  I don't get it, Make it a paid app and that would guarantee it.

Comment: Use the official distribution channels, maybe check the recipe as provided by Apple, and that's all you need to care about.

Comment: @SamB Not quite. It would be nice to have the email of the user from Apple but it is impossible for obvious reasons. I need something representing the paid user to tie his/her account to.

Comment: @Eiko I couldn't find any recipe that fits my need, that's why I'm asking here. If you think I might have missed it, please point it out.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Introduction.html is all there is, and all it needs.

Comment: This looks like the anchor I need @Eiko, thanks for the link.